# InvalidRallyTypeNameError

Tags: rally, pyral

Am trying to access the Rally through Rally API key, and am able to connect to Rally. But when i tried to get the list of User stories under a project, am getting InvalidRallyTypeNameError.

Here is my code to connect to Rally

`rally=Rally(server="rally1.rallydev.com", apikey="MyAPIkey", workspace='MyWorkspace',projectc='Helloworld')`

to get the list of Stories under a project

```
response=rally.get("project", fetch=False, limit=10) //here is where am getting the error
```

Please let me know, where am getting wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To get user stories in a project hit `hierarchicalrequirement` endpoint and scope it to the project. Here is a curl example, where zsessionid is set to ApiKey, and 678 is a placeholder for project's ObjectID:

```
curl --header "zsessionid:_abc123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?project=/project/678
```

Regardless of the language or Api tookit choice, you have to query on hierarchicalrequirement object. Some toolkits may allow using a 'userstory' or 'story' alias, but in the WS API object model user story is referred to as hierarchicalrequirement. Also, project does not have a user stories collection attribute.

When using python toolkit for rally, [pyral](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython) it will look like this

```
response = rally.get('HierarchicalRequirement', query=criterion, fetch=fields, order="FormattedID")
```

where you can limit the criteria to a project.